# Expo bluetooth support

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, expo

in my project I need to discover smartphones via bluetooth and send a single text information between them.
I have implemented bluetooth classic library but I cannot find any smartphone, I only find peripheral devices. This is my function to start discover devices.

```
/**
 * Start scanning for ble devices
 * @param {*} bleManager
 */
export const startScan = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await requestBluetoothPermission()

      if (!granted) {
        throw new Error(`Access fine location was not granted`)
      }

      try {
        const unpaired = await RNBluetoothClassic.startDiscovery()
        console.log(`Found ${unpaired.length} unpaired devices.`)
        unpaired.forEach(element => {
          if (element.deviceClass.majorClass == SMARTPHONE_TYPE)
          // Check if we are a smartphone
          console.log(element.name + ' ' + element.address)
        })
      } finally {
        //console.log({ devices, discovering: false })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
}
```

Anybody has some hints? I'm using Expo for develop a mobile application.
Thanks

I have tried using ble library with the same result

Comment: Are the other smartphones made visible? Can you find them using your phones system settings?

Comment: In the other device your app needs to call `RNBluetoothClassic. Accept()` the sample app with this library has the accept and connect Implemented for you to review.

Comment: In my bluetooth settigs I can see both the device, but when i startDiscovery they desappear also from settings. I will try with the accept method, Thank you!

Comment: I have some dependency conflict when i reinstall react-native-bluetooth-classic. I have an expo sdk49 project, do you have any hint on how to implement a version in this expo system?@MichaelKotzjan